# JSF. Change buttons/commandButtons text style

Tags: html, css, button, jsf-2, styles

I need change the jsf(now use jsf 2.2) button text style. I didn't find any default styles in the other forums(like .ui-buttons, .ui-buttons-text-only, it doesn't work). 
As example, I need a button with sizes(200, 200, blue), in the center of this rectangle new (20,20, white) and the simple text "blah". If 
try

```
<h:button value="Logout" outcome="welcome" styleClass="button">
    <h:outputLabel value="blah" styleClass="some_style">
</h:button>
```

result will be next -> button, after it the text 'blah', but I need text inside button. 
Have anyone same problem?
I need much same butons and commandButtons. Maybe some can give advice about reasons to create own jsf element with need parameters and styles?

Thx

Comment: What about `<h:commandButton value="blah" action="welcome" styleClass="button" />`?

Comment: Ok, what css code allow change size, color, border-radius and etc of  background area for font in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Because there is small space in comment section, I post it as answer.

For changing background, font size, style of button the following syntax and styles can be used:

**html**

```
<h:commandButton value="blah" action="welcome" styleClass="richButton" />
```

**css**

```
.richButton {
    margin:0 5px 0 0;
    padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;
    height:29px;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#262626;
    font-weight:bold;
    border:1px #ccc solid;
    border-radius:5px;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    /* IE10 Consumer Preview */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #E3E3E3 100%);
    /* Mozilla Firefox */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #E3E3E3 100%);
    /* Opera */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #E3E3E3 100%);
    /* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #FFFFFF), color-stop(1, #E3E3E3));
    /* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #E3E3E3 100%);
    /* W3C Markup, IE10 Release Preview */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 0%, #E3E3E3 100%);
}
.richButton:hover:enabled {
    /* IE10 Consumer Preview */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #CCCCCC 100%);
    /* Mozilla Firefox */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #CCCCCC 100%);
    /* Opera */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #CCCCCC 100%);
    /* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #FFFFFF), color-stop(1, #CCCCCC));
    /* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #CCCCCC 100%);
    /* W3C Markup, IE10 Release Preview */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 0%, #CCCCCC 100%);
}
.richButton:active:enabled {
    /* IE10 Consumer Preview */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F0F0F0 0%, #CCCCCC 100%);
    /* Mozilla Firefox */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F0F0F0 0%, #CCCCCC 100%);
    /* Opera */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F0F0F0 0%, #CCCCCC 100%);
    /* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #F0F0F0), color-stop(1, #CCCCCC));
    /* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F0F0F0 0%, #CCCCCC 100%);
    /* W3C Markup, IE10 Release Preview */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #F0F0F0 0%, #CCCCCC 100%);
}
.richButton:disabled {
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #888888;
}
```

You need change size, border size, border radius, background.

Comment: Actually, it's not what I really need. In the end it's must look like text in the center of white rectangle, which is in the center of black rectangle.